# Immunity Debugger - Memory Breakpoint

Tags: immunity-debugger, breakpoint

Is there a way to stop execution each time some memory address is accessed?

Answer (score 4):

## Yes

For a memory access breakpoint<sup>1</sup>, just `right click` the desired address > `Breakpoint` > `Memory, on access`:

[image: Code hwbp]

The same applies to values in the hex dump:

[image: Data hwbp]

1: A breakpoint on *access* will break whenver the address is read, written or executed. An *execution* breakpoint will *never* break on read/write.